# Purpose of splitting a select query into chunks?

Tags: sql

Edit: the example was bad, caused answers unrelated to the question.
Given a large select query, in a simple program like:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,    
                                     ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet srs = stmt.executeQuery(
    "SELECT AGE FROM USERS");
while (srs.next()) {
        ageStdDevAccumulator += Math.Pow(averageAge - srs.getInt("AGE"),2);
}
int ageStdDev= Math.Sqrt(ageStdDevAccumulator / userCount);
```

I understand that once the executeQuery is ran, then the entire column of user ages is sent from the database to the program. Is that right? Could this cause a memory overflow on the server if there are too many users in the database? If so it is then possible to break the select query up into smaller chunks? And if so, it is possible to let a compiler figure this out on its own?

Thanks,
A database-noob programmer.

Comment: This is a perfect example of how not to do things - your approach gets the rows from the database and walks through them one by one, putting unnecessary stress on the database (nothing will overflow), but a query that returns the result directly might do what you need just by looking at the index (in a few I/O operations) where your approach would require f(n) I/O operations, where n is the number of rows. Even if you don't have an index the query approach is going to be so much faster. So no need to 'split' the query. Also, compiler has no knowledge of the data in the database.

Comment: So each "getInt" triggers an IO operation? The executeQuery does just some administrative operations, but doesn't transfer any actual age information from the database to the server? So this doesn't put any stress on the server's memory usage at all?

Comment: @user93197, I think it is the `srs.next()` that actually performs the IO operation - I would expect `srs.getInt` to read from a buffer. As for memory usage on the server - a query that returns one row as an answer is likely to use much less server memory than a query that returns the entire dataset. It also looks as if you have already run a previous query to return the `averageAge` and the `userCount` - if not, where are you getting these values?

Comment: @user93197, which version of SQL are you using? Many dialects of SQL (inclduding Oracle and SQLServer) have standard deviation included as a function.

Answer (score 7):

If I were to calculate average for users, I would do the following simple query

SELECT AVG(AGE) FROM USERS